# Update UI after deleting Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using delete method of HttpClient, but after that UI is not updated. I tried to use `markForCheck`, but it didn't help.

```
public articles: AlArticleShort[] = [];
public filteredArticles: AlArticleShort[] = [];
public isLoadingInProgress: boolean = true;

// in the constructor

    this.articlesSubscription = this.blogDataService.getArticles()
                .subscribe(articles => {
                    this.isLoadingInProgress = false;
                    this.articles = articles;
                    this.filteredArticles = articles;
                    this.articlesSubscription.unsubscribe();
                    this.changeDetection.markForCheck();
                });

    public onDeleteArticle(id: string): void {
        this.blogDataService.deleteArticle(id).subscribe(() => {
            this.articles = this.articles.filter(article => article.id !== id);
            // this.changeDetection.markForCheck();
        });
    }

    public deleteArticle(id: string): Observable<void> {
        return this.http.delete<void>(`/api/blog/deleteArticle/${id}`);
    }
```

If I am logging `articles.lenght`, length is correct after deleting.

Comment: You're missing the `id` argument in the response callback: `subscribe((id) => {`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @MichaelD the `id` is coming from the parameter to the method.

Comment: Reassigning the component property *should* generally cause the UI to update. Can you give a [mre] - what are your change detection settings?

Comment: Could you show your @Component decorator code?

Comment: Michael D, deleteArticle returns only message, that article is successfully deleted. It doesn't return id.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Here If the article.id is a number, You need to do typecast for onDeleteArticle argument id
like

`article.id !== Number(id)`.

Because you check the type. So that it may not remove from your array.

Comment: article.id is a string

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com. It may easy to find out the issue.